# Calling fortran executable from python using subprocess call

Tags: python, fortran, subprocess

I'm trying to call a Fortran executable from python. I'm using subprocess call. However, there is a problem with using the Fortran executable. It takes arguments only in a particular order.

```
./analyze --arg1 a --arg2 b
```

executes with an error, but

```
./analyze --arg1 b --arg2 a
```

executes properly

Since I haven't written the Fortran code, there is no way to modify that. I tried writing a python script that tries both of it this way

```
try:
  subprocess.call(["/path/to/dir/analyze","--arg1",a,"--arg2",b])
except:
  subprocess.call(["/path/to/dir/analyze","--arg1",b,"--arg2",a])
```

However, if the first execution of the Fortran binary results in an error, it exits to shell and does not return control back to python. Is there a better way to acheive this?

Comment: Using a bare `except:` like that hides too much. Suggest you use `except Exception:` instead because doing so will give you more information about what is really going on. I suspect that the problem has something to do with the arguments you're trying to pass to `call()` in both places. You could also use `except Exception as exc:`, and then `print(exc)` at the beginning of the indented block that follows.

Comment: What is the datatype of `a` and `b`?

Comment: @newkid both a and b are of type int

Comment: What kind of error does the program issue? What is the output? Fortran executable does not understand Python exceptions.

Comment: When I understand the problem a little bit I think that in case of wrong arguments the Fortran programs ends with an error message or a status set. This has to be checked so that in that case the other type calling can be used.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible that in case the wrong calling order is used the arguments are swapped (with probably a warning message to the user) and the program continues (I cannot judge it in this case as the description is quite abstract).

Comment: In the case of wrong calling order, there is a

Comment: There is what ?